# посчитать слова в текстовом файле

Tags: c#, utf-8, count

Я считаю слова в текстовом файле и сравниваю результаты с Вордом и онлайн сервисами. Результаты у нас почти равны, но где-то количество слов в моей программе больше на 1000, где-то на 2, в зависимости от текста. Вот код моей программы.

```
string localText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fils[i], Encoding.UTF8);
int wordCount = 0;
string[] words = localText.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
wordCount = words.Length;
```

fils[i] - папка файлов

Comment: [Пробельных символов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) в юникоде довольно много. Возможно, в этом причина несовпадения. / В этой [статье](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-convenience-of-system-io/) рассматривается несколько вариантов программы подсчёта слов.

Comment: А если между словами будет запятая, но не будет пробела, у вас это одно слово будет?

Comment: @CrazyElf получается одно слово, но если я добавлю разделитель "," то лишних слов станет только больше.

Comment: @МихайлоКуриця Хм, может вам нужно определять ещё "пустые" слова, состоящие из одних знаков пунктуации (и пробельных знаков) и не учитывать их при подсчёте? )  В общем, лучше придумывайте регулярку уже сразу, всё-равно к регуляркам придёте рано или поздно. А вообще попробуйте найти минимальный кусок текста, где ваш подсчёт не совпадает и проанализируйте его внимательно. Нужно найти, где начинаются различия. Это смотреть и пробовать нужно. Да и правила подсчёта могут быть разными, может где-то фрагменты меньше 3-х букв словом не считаются, например.

Comment: Можно просто регулярным выражением воспользоваться: [а-яёА-ЯЁ]+

Answer (score 2):

Следующий код должен правильно посчитать количество слов в файле txt формата:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   string localText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fils[i], Encoding.UTF8);
   MatchCollection words = Regex.Matches(localText, @"\b[\w-]+\b");
   int wordCount = words.Count;
   Console.WriteLine(wordCount);
 }
```

Однако c Word файлами возникнет проблема.
Проблема в том, что C# неправильно считывает данные из Word документов, методами класса File. Попробуйте ввести следующий код в свою программу и вы сами увидите, как C# записывает эти данные:

```
foreach(string str in words)
{
   Console.Write(str);
}
```

Примерно, в следующим формате будет записан весь текст:

> ►q????B0?0↕?O"7?D??iB??????n?◄cD?oTM?TO?S?$?3?;??;t??♂?w^??sw♦?3???♣9_1??!uc?7A?↕??jm?j[?→♠z?☺?+♣☻?6H?r??k?#^$?L??8∟T?♠'!??I?`?↔▲?????C??♂b↑???◄?Y????u'?_?r?↓L6☺0#?O?S

Для того, чтобы C# мог правильно работать с файлами Word - нужно пользоваться такими библиотеками как:

1. Либо **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word**
2. Либо **DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging** и **DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing**.

Подробнее об этой теме, вы можете прочитать в ответах под следующим вопросом:
*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072832/how-to-read-or-copy-text-from-docx-odt-doc-files*

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Автор использует Word лишь как средство для подсчёта слов. Он не работает с документами docx.